# disable memcache and apc

Tags: php, apache, memcached, apc

I'm working on a PHP script on a remote server-- apparently the caching is more than a bit too aggressive, since even after I change the code of the page, the result is the same when the page is called from a browser (I get an error about a command that I've totally commented out, and it's a simple page).

Is there a way to disable memcache/apc as a page directive rather than at the server level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this parameter is on,

```
 apc.stat=1
```

With is switch, the APC will check the modification time and clears cache when file is changed.